# What makes a CanvasRenderingContext2D a CanvasRenderingContext2D?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, metaprogramming, javascript-objects

Consider the following web page.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

I open this page in Firefox, open the JS console and type the following.

```
> document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
```

The output is as follows:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D { canvas: canvas#canvas, mozCurrentTransform: (6) […], mozCurrentTransformInverse: (6) […], mozTextStyle: "10px sans-serif", mozImageSmoothingEnabled: true, globalAlpha: 1, globalCompositeOperation: "source-over", strokeStyle: "#000000", fillStyle: "#000000", filter: "none" }
```

On the other hand, if I create an object myself and copy all of the guts of the `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, it's still just a plain object.

```
var realContext = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
var myContext = new Object()
for (var property in realContext) {
    myContext[property] = realContext[property];
}

myContext
Object { drawImage: drawImage(), beginPath: beginPath(), fill: fill(), stroke: stroke(), clip: clip(), isPointInPath: isPointInPath(), isPointInStroke: isPointInStroke(), createLinearGradient: createLinearGradient(), createRadialGradient: createRadialGradient(), createPattern: createPattern(), … }
```

**What makes a CanvasRenderingContext2D a CanvasRenderingContext2D?**

As a corollary, how can I turn my plain old object *into* a `CanvasRenderingContext2D`?

---

**Edit**: I don't care about what the JS console says. I do care that I cannot use my new context the same way I use the original one.

```
myContext.save()
TypeError: 'save' called on an object that does not implement interface CanvasRenderingContext2D
```

The goal is to be able to use the new object exactly like the old one and draw on the original canvas.

**Edit:** I've looked for solutions which do *not* require modification of the source code of the website using canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet that will start logging all accesses to any `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. I disabled the stack snippet console because it throws some errors trying to serialize the `console.log()` output, so just check the developer console for the output using F12.

```js
function intercept(value) {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'function':
    case 'object':
      return new Proxy(value, {
        get(target, key) {
          const value = Reflect.get(target, key);
          console.log('handler.get', target, key, value);
          return intercept(value);
        },
        set(target, key, value) {
          const result = Reflect.set(target, key, value);
          console.log('handler.set', target, key, value);
          return result;
        },
        apply(target, thisArg, args) {
          const value = Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args);
          console.log('handler.apply', thisArg, target, ...args, value);
          return intercept(value);
        }
      });
    default:
      return value;
  }
}

const ownPropertyDescriptorEntries = Object.entries(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype
  )
);
const interceptedPropertyDescriptorEntries = ownPropertyDescriptorEntries.map(
  ([key, { get, set, value, ...descriptor }]) => [
    key, get || set ? {
      ...descriptor,
      get() {
        console.log('descriptor.get', this, key);
        return intercept(Reflect.apply(get, this, []));
      },
      set(value) {
        console.log('descriptor.set', this, key, value);
        return intercept(Reflect.apply(set, this, [value]));
      }
    } : {
      ...descriptor,
      value: intercept(value)
    }
  ]
);

Object.defineProperties(
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype,
  Object.fromEntries(
    interceptedPropertyDescriptorEntries
  )
);

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

console.log(context.lineWidth);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100).data[0] = 255;
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

```
descriptor.get CanvasRenderingContext2D lineWidth
1
descriptor.set CanvasRenderingContext2D fillStyle red
handler.apply CanvasRenderingContext2D ƒ getImageData() { [native code] } 0 0 100 100 ImageData
handler.get ImageData data Uint8ClampedArray(40000)
handler.set Uint8ClampedArray(40000) 0 255
```

#### References

- [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
- [`handler.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get)
- [`handler.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set)
- [`handler.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply)
- [`Reflect.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get)
- [`Reflect.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set)
- [`Reflect.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply)
- [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors)
- [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I initially tested this on a simple example, but it seems that this causes the canvas to render a black screen when I try it on a slightly more [complex example](https://signalcat.github.io/animationSandbox/canvasPlay.html). Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @merlin2011 actually I slowed down the `requestAnimationFrame` and it still doesn't render anything. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @merlin2011 it seems most likely because `fillStyle` is being set to a `Proxy` instead of a true `CanvasGradient`

Comment: is there a way to change the proxy so that the properties are set to real objects,  but merely logged when they are set?

Comment: @merlin2011 possibly... doing so would involve checking if an object is a `Proxy`, which would require meta-meta-programming.

Comment: @merlin2011 I wrote up a generic duplicate target for metaprogramming with `Proxy` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52452513/1541563). It's related, but not directly applicable to this question. Just thought you might be interested.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hey man, I have a question (open) related to this, if you're free, please check it now!