# Why do this setter is not giving me intercepted values when I proxy it?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm sure the way I create proxy is correct because I can see that the setter has been proxified when I log the property into devtools console.

The problem doesn't happen with properties that are functions, their interception works fine.

I mostly followed this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304649/14659574)'s answer to build this. Altho, I must say that answer looked complicated to understand so I stripped off many things from it to get into simple style which you can see from below code.

```js
class Hook {
    constructor(object) {
        if (object) {
            this.object = object;
        }
    }

    add(object) {
        this.object = object;
    }


    proxy(handler) {
        return new Proxy(this.object, handler);
    }
};


const hook = new Hook();

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype).forEach(function (property) {
    let propertyDescription = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, property);

    const proxyPropertyDescription = {
        configurable: propertyDescription.configurable,
        enumerable: propertyDescription.enumerable
    }

    if (typeof propertyDescription.value === "function") {
        const handle = {
            apply(target, thisArg, args) {
                // forward invocation to underlying function
                console.log("apply", thisArg, target, args)

                return target.apply(thisArg, thisArg, args)
            }
        };

        hook.add(propertyDescription.value)

        proxyPropertyDescription.writable = propertyDescription.writable;
        proxyPropertyDescription.value = hook.proxy(handle, true);
    }

    if (propertyDescription.set) {
        const handle = {
            set(target, key, value) {

                // forward access to underlying property
                Reflect.set(target, key, value);

                console.log("set", target, key, value);
            }
        };

        hook.add(propertyDescription.set)

        proxyPropertyDescription.set = hook.proxy(handle, true);
    }

    Object.defineProperty(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, property, proxyPropertyDescription);
})

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// My target but it never get proxified 
ctx.font = "14px 'Arial'";

// But functions like this works....
ctx.fill("red");


// I can see that on Devtools when I log this Property has been set to Proxy
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, "font"));
```

Comment: "*I can see that on Devtools when I log this Property has been set to Proxy*" - I cannot. And alas, it does not make sense to proxy a property descriptor. You simply want to *wrap* the original setter, there's not point in using a proxy here. At best, you should wrap `ctx` itself in a proxy.

Comment: Also, `propertyDescription.set` is a function that will be called when the property is set. That triggers the `apply` trap of the proxy around that function, not the `set`  trap.

Comment: @Bergi Please see,     Object.defineProperty(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, property, proxyPropertyDescription);

Comment: @Bergi I redefine the property with the new description. It's how things are done with the question I linked earlier. Funny enough, if property is a function then proxy works fine but when it comes to getters, setters it's not while the question I linked itself works fine!

Comment: @Bergi No. I use propertyDescription.set to check whether property is setter or  getter....

Comment: @Bergi It make no sense to proxy "ctx" itself when I want to intercept every contexts. It must be done through the prototype of renderingContext.

Comment: I'll have to take back my "*I cannot see that when I log this Property has been set to Proxy*". The output of StackSnippet was confusing me, which doesn't display any proxy. In the console one can see it.

Comment: "*It's how things are done with the question I linked earlier.*" - not exactly, your handler is missing the `apply` trap. And the answer to that other question is not necessarily a good one.

Comment: What's the point of that `hook` instance btw? That class looks like nothing but boilerplate around a simple `new Proxy` call to me. Are you planning to do more with it?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I'm planning to do more with Hook class.  Other question answer not clear to me so I did things on my way. Stack Snippet doesn't display Proxy. Proxy follows transparent virtualization but one can use Devtool console to view it.

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand what you mean by apply trap. If you can make a answer below, I would be greatful.

Comment: Can you expand on what you intend to do with the hook thing? I can adjust my answer for it then. Currently, it's as a good a static helper function, and you don't even create multiple instances of it.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, there I didn't create multiple instances because it's easier to follow from top. I plan to make this logic into class itself allowing more objects  other than CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype to be intercepted.

Comment: @Bergi Possibly, I will in future modify body of handler (arg) inside proxy method of hook class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix getters/setters with proxies. Use either, not both.

Here is a solution with using property descriptors only:

```js
const hook = {
    wrapMethod(name, method) {
        return function(...args) {
            console.log("applying method "+name, args);
            return method.apply(this, args);
        };
    },
    wrapSetter(name, setter) {
        return function(value) {
            console.log("setting "+name, value);
            return setter.call(this, value);
        };
    }
};

const proto = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, name);

    if (!descriptor.configurable) {
        console.log("Cannot hook onto immutable ."+name);
        continue;
    } else if (typeof descriptor.value == "function") {
        descriptor.value = hook.wrapMethod(name, descriptor.value);
    } else if (descriptor.set) {
        descriptor.set = hook.wrapSetter(name, descriptor.set);
    } else {
        console.log("Did not hook onto ."+name, descriptor);
    }
    Object.defineProperty(proto, name, descriptor);
}


var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "14px 'Arial'";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(130, 190, 40, 60);
```

Here is a solution using proxies only:

```js
const hook = {
    wrapMethod(name, method) {
        return function(...args) {
            console.log("applying method "+name, args);
            return method.apply(this, args);
        };
    },
    wrapSetter(name, setter) {
        return function(value) {
            console.log("setting "+name, value);
            return setter.call(this, value);
        };
    }
};

const contextProto = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
const canvasProto = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype;
const getContext = canvasProto.getContext;
canvasProto.getContext = function(...args) {
    const ctx = getContext.apply(this, args);
    if (ctx && Object.getPrototypeOf(ctx) == contextProto)
        Object.setPrototypeOf(ctx, proxy);
    return ctx;
};

const proxy = new Proxy(contextProto, {
    get(target, name, receiver) {
         const value = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
         return typeof value == "function" ? hook.wrapMethod(name, value) : value;
    },
    set(target, name, value, receiver) {
        hook.wrapSetter(name, function(value) {
            Reflect.set(target, name, value, this);
        }).call(receiver, value);
    },
});


var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "14px 'Arial'";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(130, 190, 40, 60);
```

This is rather inefficient as the methods and setters are getting wrapped on every access, not just once.

Comment: Why are you assigning a function to canvasProto.getContext?  I need it to work independently from HTML5Canvas Element

Comment: I still can't understand your code overall.

Comment: I can understand your first code and it reassemble my own code but the second code is very hard...

Comment: You said "*I want to intercept every contexts. It must be done through the prototype of renderingContext.*" in the comments. If you want to go by proxies (which I would say you shouldn't), you would need to intercept the creation of the contexts, that's what the overridden `getContext` does. So yeah, just use the first approach.

Comment: The linked question answer doesn't intercept creation of contexts rather hooking directly to CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype which is what I want.

Comment: if you go to that answer, you can't find any "HTMLCanvasElement.prototype" over there

Comment: @jeffbRTC Then you cannot use proxies. The way in which the linked answer uses proxies just doesn't make sense - they're totally superfluous in the approach of overwriting `prototype` properties, as demonstrated in my first snippet.

Comment: @jeffbRTC No, proxies cannot do everything. And most crucially, they cannot replace already existing objects.

Comment: @jeffbRTC If you don't want to modify `HTMLCanvasElement` and still wanted to use a proxy, you'd need to write `const ctx = new Proxy(canvas.getContext("2d"), proxyHandler)` in every place where you are constructing a context.

Comment: The question I linked already do so without a doubt. It use only CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype

Comment: @jeffbRTC So does the first snippet in my answer, without proxies. What is the problem you're trying to solve, why do you think you'd need proxies?